# Tunneling Http traffic from A to B using SSH

Tags: http, networking, ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I am very new to networking and trying to understand SSH.

I have this setup

Device `A` : serving web app on a static `192.X.X.X`

Device`B` : can access the web app through `192.X.X.X`

Device `C`: connected to `B` but on a different network `10.X.X.X`, can only SSH to `B`

Now my question is can I somehow tunnel the HTTP traffic on `192.X.X.X` from `B` to `C` or is that even possible.

i.e., Can I open a browser on `C` type an IP and see the web app similar to how I would on `B`

Comment: SSH isn’t probably what you are looking for, SSH is for shells, not for a proxy. Either way, this question would be better suited to superuser.com

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b Thanks for suggestion added question to superuser.com

Comment: Got answered on superuser.com -> https://superuser.com/questions/1774066/tunneling-http-traffic-from-a-to-b-using-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the device `C` you run:

```
ssh device_b_user@Y.Y.Y.Y -L 8080:192.X.X.X:80
```

Where `Y.Y.Y.Y` is the IP of the device `B` and `192.X.X.X` is the IP of device `A`.

That will open the port 8080 on `C` and redirect the traffic to `192.X.X.X` port 80, so you can access the web app on `C` navigating to `localhost:8080` at the web browser.